# Make ElasticSearch Search using nest that return no value if QueryContainer is null

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I need to make a Query that return no value if the QueryContainer is null. Here a simplify version of my problem. I have a few if that check if my args is nullOrEmpty and if the value is valid, I add a QueryContainer in the query

the code that start the Search:

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<ClientTaskModel>(s => s.Index(new[] { config.ClientIndexName })
                                                                .From(args.Index)
                                                                .Size(args.Count)
                                                                .Query(fp => FilterTask(fp, args)));
```

The function that create the QueryContainer for the Search

```
private QueryContainer FilterTask(QueryContainerDescriptor<ClientTaskModel> container, GetSimilarClientsTaskArgs args)
{    
         QueryContainer fieldQuery = null;

         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.Sin))
         {
            fieldQuery |= container.Match(g => g.Field(f => f.Sin).Query(args.Sin).Verbatim());
         }

         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.Email))
         {
            fieldQuery |= container.Match(g => g.Field(f => f.Email).Query(args.Email).Verbatim());
         } 

         return !container.Match(g => g.Query(args.ClientId.ToString()).Field(f => f.ClientId).Verbatim()) &&
                container.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.ClientType).Terms(compareType) && fieldQuery 
 }
```

The problem is when the SIN and the Email is nullOrEmpty, the fieldQuery end up null and the query only check if the ClientId and the ClientType match, but I need to return no result in this situation.

Comment: Something like this could work..Or just take if all field are empty before all FilterTask? (fieldQuery  == null) ? (fieldQuery |= "a filter all') : fieldQuery;

Comment: I thought about doing that before the FilterTask, but my example is simplify and in reality I have 10 fields to check. I keep it as a possibility, but maybe there an other way. 

(fieldQuery == null) ? (fieldQuery |= "a filter all') will not work in my case. I need to have no result if the fieldQuery == null.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "no result in this situation". If `SIN` and `Email` are both null or empty, just don't execute the query at all? Matching on `null` or empty string will never work, even with verbatim.